# If x and y are two integers with value 1& 2 respectively. What is the meaning of the statement y= - -x--;

Tags: c++, c

I wrote the following program which gave me output 0 1 but i didn't understand how

```
main()
{
  int i = 1, m = 2;
  m= - - i--;
  printf("%d %d", i, m);
}
```

Comment: Don't write code like that. It is being intentionally confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's consider:

```
m = - - i--;
```

Here, `- -` applies the unary minus twice. This is effectively a no-op. Thus the above can be simplified to

```
m = i--;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
m = i;
i = i - 1;
```

Thus the correct output is `0 1`.

Answer (score 8):

-- and - - are different: - - is equal to -(-()) operator,
when you call

```
m= - - i--;
```

you are decreasing i by 1 and then you are multiplying the new value by -1 two times which does not change the result.

Answer (score 4):

The post-increment operator (`--`) yields the value of `i` (afterwards it's negated twice), and then decrements it. So `m` will be 1, and `i` will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

`- -x--` can be write like `- (- (x--))`.

`x--` substract 1 from x, but return x before the substraction. So y will take the value of x. And x is now equals to `x - 1`.